# BeautifulSoup find without class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html code (website is `www.kupindo.com`):

```
<div class="holder_content" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="holder_pagination">
            <a class="next_prev_link" href="/Knjige/Strucna-literatura/Biznis-i-organizacija/artikli/61_strana_2">« Prethodna</a> 
            <a href="/Knjige/Strucna-literatura/Biznis-i-organizacija/artikli/61">1</a> 
            <span style="float:left">...</span>
            <a class="pagination_active_page">3</a> 
            <span style="float:left">...</span>
            <a href="/Knjige/Strucna-literatura/Biznis-i-organizacija/artikli/61_strana_313">313</a> 
            <a class="next_prev_link" href="/Knjige/Strucna-literatura/Biznis-i-organizacija/artikli/61_strana_4">Sledeća »</a>

            <form action="/Knjige/Strucna-literatura/Biznis-i-organizacija/artikli/61" name="formPagination" id="formPagination" method="post" style="width:170px">
                <label>Idi na stranu:</label>
                <input name="iStr" id="iStr" class="textbox" type="text">
                <input name="butIdiNaStranu" id="butIdiNaStranu" value="Idi" type="submit">
            </form> 
         </div>     
</div>
```

And I need to extract last page number (313) in order to iterate through all the pages. How can I do that when I don't have any class. 
I was just able to extract number for the first page using:

```
broj=corba.find_all("div",{"class":"holder_pagination"})
```

and then using:

```
broj.find("a").text
```

and when I do `len(broj)`, i get 1 (because there is just one holder_pagination, I know that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `find` and `find_all` conversely. There is a single `holder_pagination`, so find that with `find`:

```
broj = corba.find("div",{"class":"holder_pagination"})
```

Then use `find_all` to find all links:

```
links = broj.find_all("a")
```

Now you have a list of links, so just select the second from last and you have it:

```
links[-2].text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml') 
# a is your code above ...<div class="holder_content" style="margin-top:20px">...

broj = soup.find("div",{"class":"holder_pagination"})
find_next = broj.findAll('a',{'class':'next_prev_link'})[1]
if find_next.text == 'Sledeća »':
    print("Ima sledece stranica (There's a next page)")
else:
    print("Nema sledece stranica (There's no next page)")
```

Now instead of printing Ima sledeca strana what we can do is, get the href
and do something with that Page, example:

```
broj = soup.find("div",{"class":"holder_pagination"})
try:
    find_next = broj.findAll('a',{'class':'next_prev_link'})[1]
except Exception:
    print("Doslo je do greske ili smo dosli do kraja, nismo mogli da pronadjemo SLEDECA - stranica")
if find_next.text == 'Sledeća »':
    print("Ima Sledeca strana(There's another page)")
    pozovemo_neku_funkciju_to_do_something()
    # I sad mozemo da otvorimo sledecu stranu najbolje da napravis funkciju za ovo
    # I kad otvorimo sledecu stranicu i kad prikupis sve te podatke i ostalo opet na kraju proveravamo da li ima sledeca
    # I sve dok ima sledeca nastavljamo sa radnjom
else:
    print("Nema sledece stranica (There's no next page)")
```

*I've written most of the code and the comments in Serbian since that's the best way for the questioner to understand, hopefully. If anyone else has any uncertainties, make sure to leave a comment.*